# A complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n$-chromatic

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

It is true that a complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n$-chromatic.But is it true that if a graph with $n$ vertices has chromatic number $n$, then it is complete?

Comment: Hint: For each $n$, consider the graph $K_n-e$, where $e$ is an arbitrary edge. Can you color each $K_n-e$ with $n-1$ colors?

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that by showing that a (simple, undirected, finite) graph of order $n$ with chromatic number $n$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges (the maximum number of edges possible in such a graph).

Assume $G$ with $n$ vertices is $n$-chromatic, then there are $n$ disjoint independent sets, each representing one of the $n$ colour classes of $G$. Since $G$ is $n$-chromatic, the $n$ colour classes must be pairwise adjacent, or otherwise we could reuse colours. (trivially these independent sets consists of a single vertex ...)

By simple application of the Handshaking lemma, the number of edges follows and therefore $G$ is complete.

Actually, the general result for $k$-chromatic graphs is discussed in this network [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135688/prove-that-every-k-chromatic-graph-has-size-m-geq-binom-k2?rq=1).